# UE5 - How do I Set Camera Shake Variables during Play Mode?

Tags: camera, unreal-engine5, perlin-noise, unreal

I am looking to update the **Rotation Frequency Multiplier** value via a slider on the UI so that I can adjust the frequency of the camera shake. I am using a cine camera actor with a camera shake blueprint added to it, for the root shake pattern I am using the **Perlin Noise Camera Shake Pattern**.

In the level blueprint, where I am trying to update this variable, I have created this node:

[image]

But the target as you can see is a "Perlin Noise Camera Shake Pattern Object Reference". How can I get this reference so that I can update the value? and is this the correct way to go about it?

I am using Unreal Engine 5.2

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)